# Unity Random is detroying all objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, destroy

I'm trying to make the system work so that when a game starts and for each wall, it will either be in the game or not, randomly. Somehow, when I run it, it either keeps or destroys all the walls. How do I fix this?

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WallGen : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject wallObject;
    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        generate();
    }

    void generate()
    {
        int number = rnd.Next(1, 5);
        if (number == 2)
        {
            OnDestroy();
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy(){
        Destroy(wallObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: Try using Random.Range instead of System.Random: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: when I try int number = rnd.Range(1, 5); it gives me an error that it cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Comment: Don't use System.Random, delete all that. Use the link I posted instead.

Comment: I linked `Random.Range` document in my other answer but still, you decided to use something else.... Read the document. It shows how to generate random number in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do `new System.Random()` it is initialised using the clock. Now as the Start function is called at the same time, you get the same value for all the `gameobjects`. You should keep a single `Random` instance for all `gameobjects` and keep using `Next` on the same instance.
**Or the easy solution**
just Use `Random.Range (1,5)` instead of `rnd.Next(1, 5);`

As a side note, don't use the function name `OnDestroy`, as it is one of the [MonoBehaviour functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html) in Unity and is called automatically when the attached gameobject is destroyed.